# Trigger usePosition() custom hook onClick element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm facing some troubles when I try to trigger [usePosition](https://github.com/trekhleb/use-position) hook in a `onClick` event.

What I want to achieve is to delay the geolocation permission prompt triggered by the browser until the user clicks some element.

What I've tried so far is a bunch of variations of the following code, but without success:

```
const IndexPage = () => {
        const [geolocation, setGeolocation] = useState({});
        const [isGeolocationActive, triggerGeolocation] = useState(false);
        let currentPosition = usePosition();

        function handleGeolocation() {
            if (isGeolocationActive) {
                setGeolocation(currentPosition)
                console.log('geolocation', geolocation)
            } else triggerGeolocation(true);
        }

        return (
            <Layout>
                <Wrapper type={`list`} classNames={`wrapper pet__cards cards__list`}>
                    <Card>
                        <Image/>
                        <div onClick={() => handleGeolocation()}>Click me to share my location</div>
```

I've tried to set a `useState` hook (initially set to false) which should control and handle the `usePosition` hook if is set to true but the browser still asking for geolocation permission as soon as I land on the page.

Edit: I've also tried to put the `usePosition` hook in another component and call it `onClick` event. However, in this case, I face some hooks rules error such as:

> "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved the issue using `usePosition` hook in another component, something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {usePosition} from "use-position";

const Geolocation = () => {
    let currentPosition = usePosition();

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{currentPosition.latitude}</p>
        </div>
    )
};
export default Geolocation;
```

While in my main component I've used a `useState` hook which controls the rendering like this:

```
const IndexPage = () => {
    const [geolocation, setGeolocation] = useState('');

    function handleGeolocation() {
        setGeolocation(<Geolocation/>);
    }

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Card>
                <Image/>
                <div onClick={() => handleGeolocation()}>Click me to share my location</div>
                {geolocation}
                ...
```